# jqGrid multiple grid in same page with different alert box position

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

### How do we position a alert message dialog box on the middle of jgGrid?

I am using two `jgGrids` on the page and tried with `alerttop`, `alertleft` as suggested by `Oleg` in 
[jqGrid warning please select row position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719349/jqgrid-warning-please-select-row-position)

But the problem is, the same alert box options are reused for all the grids in the page.
In `jqGrid` ids for alert box is static and not grid context based.

(Line no: 8531 in 4.4.0 source file)

```
var alertIDs = { themodal: 'alertmod', modalhead: 'alerthd', modalcontent: 'alertcnt' }
```

and the below code is executed for only one grid

```
*if ($("#" + alertIDs.themodal).html() === null) {
                    if (!o.alerttop && !o.alertleft) {*
```

Due to this i cant able to position alert boxes for each grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, that it's a problem in jqGrid. The same problems was in Add/Edit/Delete/View dialogs, but the problem is already fixed.

I suggest that you just change the line

```
var alertIDs = { themodal: 'alertmod', modalhead: 'alerthd', modalcontent: 'alertcnt' }
```

to

```
var alertIDs = {themodal: 'alertmod_' + this.p.id,
        modalhead: 'alerthd_' + this.p.id, modalcontent: 'alertcnt_' + this.p.id}
```

in the file `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` directly.

**UPDATED**: After writing of the answer I posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/make-alertmod-dialog-unique-for-every-grid/#p27301). Now I can inform everybody that [the corresponding fix](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/a21168b84bbedeaae823287c3b8de7f5c4dcb8e3) is already included in the main jqGrid code on the github. So the next release of jqGrid (with the version higher as the current 4.4.1) will include it.

Comment: @Murali: You are welcome! I'll post the suggestion as the bug fix to trirand.

Comment: @Murali: Just for the information look at the **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Excellent!. Thanks for your continuous support on widely used very good jQGrid plugin.